# React Custom Hook Behind the scene

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

the result of the code is

1. first call
2. outside useEffect
3. before return
4. inside useEffect
5. first call
6. outside useEffect
7. before return
8. inside useEffect
9. first call
10. outside useEffect
11. before return

but why?

- how inside useEffect be called twice
- how after outside useEffect there is no inside useEffect
- why it did not make infinite loop because data is being re-created every time so it should effect useApi

```
function useApi(data, initial){
    const [name, setName] = useState(initial)
    console.log("outside useEffect")
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("inside useEffect")
        fetch(data.name,{
           method: data.method,
           body: data.body
       }).then((response) => response.json()).then((response) => {
           setName(response.id)
       })
    }, [data])
    return [name, setName]
}

function App() {
  console.log("first call")
  const data =  {
    name: "http://localhost:8000/api/kebap",
    method: "GET"
  }
  const [info, setInfo] = useApi(data,
   "10")
  console.log("before return")
  return <div> {info} </div>
}
```

Comment: Well, it **does** cause an infinite loop! (Might not happen in your case if the fetch call to endpoint `http://localhost:8000/api/kebap` doesn't succeed.) Working example with infinite loop here: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-firefly-3u24vs?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Also, Benjamin's answer captures the solution to this correctly. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71177141/1773808

Comment: About your other question. The "inside useEffect" is printed after "before return" precisely because of how `useEffect` works. `useEffect` callback is called after each* render. *Depends on the dependency array. In your example since the reference to data is different each time it will be called after every render and forever.

Comment: I like how you're approaching React though. Really trying to understand how things work under the hood!

Comment: @PYigit are you using `<React.StrictMode>` ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
  const data = {
    name: 'http://localhost:8000/api/kebap',
    method: 'GET',
  };
```

This object, `const data` is being created every render. It is also used as the a dependency for your `useEffect` hook. This means that the `useEffect` hook will be called every time you render, causing an infinite loop.

The solution, is to memoize the object, or in this case, simply move it outside of the component.

```js
function useApi(data, initial) {
  const [name, setName] = useState(initial);
  console.log('outside useEffect');
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('inside useEffect');
    fetch(data.name, {
      method: data.method,
      body: data.body,
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        setName(response.id);
      });
  }, [data]);
  return [name, setName];
}

const data = {
  name: 'http://localhost:8000/api/kebap',
  method: 'GET',
};

function App() {
  console.log('first call');
  const [info, setInfo] = useApi(data, '10');
  console.log('before return');
  return <div> {info} </div>;
}
```

Another way, would be to use `useMemo`. This would be useful, if your `data` object would be dynamically created.

```js
function App() {
  console.log('first call');
  const data = useMemo(() => ({
    name: 'http://localhost:8000/api/kebap',
    method: 'GET',
  }),[]);
  const [info, setInfo] = useApi(data, '10');
  console.log('before return');
  return <div> {info} </div>;
}
```

Comment: But it did not make infinitive loop as I said. I ask why it did not make.

Comment: @PYigit ah, I misread that last part. Hmmm...

Answer (score -1):

Using a better custom hook, `usePromise`, your `App` would look like this. Remember to always handle the `fetching` and `error` states of your app.

```js
function App() {
  const [{ fetching, error, data = "10"}, retry] = usePromise(_ =>
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/kebap")
      .then(res => res.json())
  )
  return <div>
    { fetching
    ? <p>Fetching...</p>
    : error
    ? <p>Error: {error.message}</p>
    : <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
    }
  </div>
}
```

Here is a minimal verifiable example of `usePromise`.

- Input of `() => Promise`
- Returns `[state, retry]`

  - `state` contains `{fetching, error, data}` so you can know the status of the promise
  - `retry` is a function that allows you to rerun the promise

```js
function usePromise(thunk) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    fetching: true,
    error: null,
    data: null
  })
  const [timestamp, setTimestamp] = React.useState(Date.now())
  React.useEffect(_ => {
    setState({ ...state, fetching: true })
    thunk()
      .then(data => setState({ fetching: false, error: null, data }))
      .catch(error => setState({ fetching: false, error, data: null }))
  }, [timestamp])
  return [state, _ => setTimestamp(Date.now())]
}
```

Here is a demo. Click the <kbd>retry</kbd> button several times to see the effect run each time.

```js
function App() {
  const [{fetching, error, data}, retry] = usePromise(_ =>
    fetch("https://random-data-api.com/api/app/random_app").then(res => res.json())
  )
  return <div>
    <button type="button" onClick={retry} children="retry" disabled={fetching} />
    <pre>
      { fetching
      ? "Fetching..."
      : error
      ? `Error: ${error.message}`
      : JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)
      }
    </pre>
  </div>
}

function usePromise(thunk) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    fetching: true,
    error: null,
    data: null
  })
  const [timestamp, setTimestamp] = React.useState(Date.now())
  React.useEffect(_ => {
    setState({ ...state, fetching: true })
    thunk()
      .then(data => setState({ fetching: false, error: null, data }))
      .catch(error => setState({ fetching: false, error, data: null }))
  }, [timestamp])
  return [state, _ => setTimestamp(Date.now())]
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Most likely `retry` will not be implemented on a button like <kbd>retry</kbd>. Instead you can check for `error` and call `retry()` automatically in your codes.